# PHP - Inicio de sesión máximo de 3 veces pero con el mismo usuario

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo hacer para que un usuario ingrese un maximo de 3 veces con el mismo usuario?
Y si quiere logearse por 4 vez le salga un aviso de que excedió el máximo de veces de inicio de sesión, con PHP.

Claro con conexión a una base de datos MySQL y PHP.

Aquí abajo les dejo el código.

```
<?php  
    require('conexion.php');
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
        $error = '';

        $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

        $sql = "SELECT  id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
        $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        $rows=$result->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];

            header("location: ../paginas/pagina-entrada.html");
        }else{
            $error= "el nombre de usuario o contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>Login</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <div><label>Usuario</label><input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text"></div>
        <br>
        <div><label>Password</label><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></div>
        <br>
        <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div style="font-size:16px; color:#cc0000;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error): '' ; ?></div>

</body>
```

Comment: a la tabla `Usuarios` de tu bd le añades una columna `numConexiones` y lo vas incrementando cada vez que se loguea. Cuando sea `>3` no le dejas. Hasta aqui podemos decirte. Codigo no hasta que muestres lo que has intentado y expliques qué fallos o problemas tienes. Un saludo

Comment: Ésta pregunta es demasiado amplia y no respeta los estándares, por lo que debería ser cerrada, procura volver a preguntar cuando tengas un problema específico que resolver, con un ejemplo en código de tu problema.

Lee [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para no tener éste tipo de complicaciones.

Sorry @lois6b , me tentó la posibilidad de puntos fáciles.
Se que lo que debe hacerse es comentar como estoy comentando ahora.

Comment: hahaha no pasa nada, @federhico . pero que conste que solo caerian puntos faciles si hubieras elaborado la respuesta (y dejarian de ser faciles) ahaha

Comment: Acabo de actualizar y publique el código es solo un proyecto de fin de ciclo, mil disculpas estimados pero es la primera vez que público en stackoverflow.

Comment: el logeo seria en la misma pc-???

Comment: No, claro que no, el logeo sería cuando la página ya esté alojada en un hosting.

Comment: Creo que la solucion es guardar en una tabla el numero de sesiones activas que tienes y una vez que has cerrado sesión simplemente disminuir en uno las sesiones activas

Comment: Esa implementación sería en la base de datos, verdad. Gracias!

Comment: si asi es amigo, estoy escribiendo una solucion...

Comment: Sería mejor, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Un máximo de tres inicios de sesión o tres sesiones activas, y si cierra una sesión pueda abrir otra nueva, pero siempre como mucho tres a la vez?

Comment: Si exacto, Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabla Accesos

Campos

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id         |  primary key                                           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  accesos    | int, almacena el numero de veces que ingreso           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
| idusuario   |  int, almacena el id del usuario que ingresa           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|


<?php  
    require('conexion.php');
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
        $error = '';

        $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

        $sql = "SELECT  id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
        $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        $rows=$result->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $idusuario=$row['id'];

       $sql2 = "SELECT accesos FROM Accesos WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario'";
       $result2=$mysqli->query($sql2);
       $rows2=$result2->num_rows;
       if($rows2==0)
       {
          $sql3 = "insert into Accesos (accesos,idusuario) values(1,'$idusuario')";
          $result3=$mysqli->query($sql3);
       }else{
         $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
         $num_accesos=$row2['accesos'];
           if($num_accesos<3){
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];
            header("location: ../paginas/pagina-entrada.html");
               $sql4 = "update Accesos set accesos";
                ////////////////// EN ESTA PARTE INCREMENTAS EN UNO EL ACCESO
               $result4=$mysqli->query($sql4);
           }else{
                $error="Demasiadas sesiones abiertas";
              }
       }                 
        }else{
            $error= "el nombre de usuario o contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Estimado, disculpe pero la tercera columna de la tabla Accesos (idusuario) seria un foreign Key cierto?

Comment: si, relacionada con la tabla usuarios

Comment: El header("location: ../paginas/pagina-entrada.html"); debe ir despues del $result4

Comment: Amigo eres un genio, Muchas gracias, me salvaste de no jalar el ciclo.

Comment: si te sirvio aceptala como valida